# Polyline drawn is showing below buildings

Tags: mapkit, mkpolyline

The polyline is drawn showing below building.

[image]
[image]
<sub>(source: [gifyu.com](https://s3.gifyu.com/images/video_H7nmnP02_IzgB.md.gif))</sub>

How can I get the polyline top of all layers

please suggest

adding polyline as

```
   var coordinates = locationsArrToAdd.map({ (location: CLLocation!) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in
        return location.coordinate
   })
    
   let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: locationsArrToAdd.count)
    
   self.mapView.addOverlays([polyline], level: .aboveLabels)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, the highest available level you can add an overlay to is the MKOverlayLevel.aboveOverlays constant you are currently using. However, their [documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkoverlaylevel/aboveroads) that this will:

> Place the overlay above map labels, shields, or point-of-interest icons *but below annotations and 3D projections of buildings.*

From what I can see, the best solution is to disabled buildings in 3D mode, so that your polylines are visible:

```
self.mapView.showsBuildings = false
```

Comment: I need to have the 3D mode self.mapView.showsBuildings = true

thanks for adding the official documentation